# Dense_Rank over Partition By - Requiring Group By?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, dense-rank, partition-by

I have the following piece of SQL code

```
SELECT  [Group], 
        [ID], 
        CASE WHEN 
        DENSE_RANK () OVER (
            PARTITION BY [Group]
            ORDER BY COUNT([ID]) desc) < 12 
        THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END As 'Top'
  FROM [i].[dbo].[vw_name]
```

Which is returning the error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
> Column 'i.dbo.vw_name.Group' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I have scoured through as many resources as possible, but all answers say that the `Over ( Partition BY () )`  shouldn't require a `GROUP BY` clause.

I apologise if I this is  a simple question - but I have been stuck for a while now.

Comment: It's because your using the `count ` aggregate.

Comment: That was my suspicion. Is there any way around this? I basically want to flag the top 11 groups over all the ID's.

Comment: Yeah, you need two levels of analytic functions.

Comment: When you say two levels, do you mean two separate queries? Sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie to all of this.
My query works perfectly when I do the following

```
SELECT [Group], CASE WHEN DENSE_RANK () OVER ( ORDER BY COUNT([ID]) desc) < 12 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END As 'Top'
  FROM [i].[dbo].[vw_nameI]
  GROUP BY [Group]
```

But I'm trying to get it all in a select statement so I can add it to the vw_name itself.

Comment: Presumably you want all the id values back too. Refer to answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
with agg as (
    select grp, id,
        count(*) over (partition by grp) as cnt
    from vw_name
)
select grp, id, cnt,
    dense_rank() over (order by cnt desc) as rnk
from agg
```

Comment: How would I then add the results of this query into the vw_name itself. I am wanting to add it as a column.

Comment: Well unless it's complicated maybe you just place the existing view inside `agg` and just append the `cnt` column there. No promises that's the full story.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is quite a complicated view already. I might just save the working query as a view itself, and see if I can do a simple join that way.

Comment: I imagine it will work either way. There might be some downfalls to chaining views and there might be a benefit to still having a view that doesn't compute the ranking. I guess you'll have to play with it.